# process.env.varible undefined in nest.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I am using nest.js and I want to import object defined in auth.parameters.ts file. File is defined as below.  It appears environmental variable is not visible unless below variable is declared in class.

```
export const obj = {
    somevar : process.env.CUSTOM_VAR,

};
```

In my other classes I would like to import the file with import {SecurityParameters } from '../auth/auth.parameters'

and access the variable with console.log(SecurityParameters.somevar).

I can access the variable directly using process.env.CUSTOM_VAR or

I get undefined if I use somevar : process.env.CUSTOM_VAR in other file.

Comment: Do you use a `.env` file, `dotenv`, `@nestjs/config`? We need more info here.

Comment: Yes, I use .env file. I think process.env variable works only in class. It’s not visible if object is not declared in a class.

Comment: How do you populate `process.env` from the `.env` file? `dotenv` or `@nestjs/config` or something else entirely?

Comment: I populate using .env and I have @nestjs/config in app.module.ts with isGobal setting to true. My environment variable is visible in all files except the file where const obj is defined

Comment: That means some module loads/imports `'../auth/auth.parameters'` before `@nestjs/config` is loaded, but it was loaded by the time that your class is instantiated.

Answer (score 6):

As you're using Nest's `ConfigModule`, then unless you're creating a [custom config file](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#custom-configuration-files) you shouldn't be doing anything with `process.env`. Instead, you should be injecting Nest's `ConfigService` where you need the environment variables and using `this.configService.get('CUSTOM_VARIABLE')` (or whatever value you need). To get started with this, you need to import the config module

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot()],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

You can pass `{ isGlobal: true }` to the `forRoot()` call to make the `ConfigService` injectable anywhere in your application.

If you want a different approach where you can use the `process.env` object instead, you can add this as the **first two** lines of your `main.ts`

```js
import { config } from 'dotenv';
config();
```

Nest calls this (or something similar) under the hood in the `ConfigService`, but that doesn't make it immediately available.

Comment: So does this mean one can't use configservice outside of a class. Cus in my own case that's what I'm trying to do. My configservice works well when injected in a class but how do I use it when not in a class

Comment: I have a secret variable for jwt register config and it's not in a class but I also don't want my secret exposed inside the app

Answer (score 0):

you can call process.evt.xxxx in function, if call other >> undefined